# Need website help, Adding a shop. Shopify

Tags: javascript, html, shopify

I am inserting a shopify store into my website.  They have a widget they use that pulls up a  collection and you can add to cart and check out.  The embedded code they gave me is below and should be inserted between  .

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var ShopifyStoreConfig = {shop:"glow-station-shop.myshopify.com", collections:[14849869]};
  (function() {
    var s = document.createElement('script'); s.type = 'text/javascript'; s.async = true; 
    s.src = "//widgets.shopifyapps.com/assets/shopifystore.js";
    var x = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; x.parentNode.insertBefore(s, x);
  })();  
</script>
```

I then have to place the following code where I want them to click in my actual site.

```
    <a href='#shopify-store'>View my Store</a>
```

My question is what do I need to change to that I can have multiple instances of this connecting to different products.  An example would be a "view my store" and a "view my store2" button both connecting to different collections.

The "View my store2" code is the same as the 1st but the collections:[14849869] changes to a different number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a index.html with several iframes. Each iframe would have the code for its store and `<base target="_parent" />`